# Study of category and functor

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, self-learning, sheaf-theory

I am going to start study of Category and Functors and sheaf theory. What are good text/ lecture notes to start with?

I have not done any prior course on category theory and homological algebra or Algebraic topology. But I had done courses in Group, rings, modules, galois theory, little bit of algebraic geometry, and point set topology.

Comment: @Stefan. Thanks for adding self-learning tag. I was not aware of it.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews added that tag. I added the others.

Comment: Generally a good idea, when asking for references, to give some idea of your current level and knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your current level, you may find Part I of [Ravi Vakil's notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/) on algebraic geometry useful. I find them extremely readable, and you may also be interested in how these theories are applied in the rest of the notes.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Saunders Mac Lane's book "Categories for the Working Mathematician".